# Is this a horseweed?

Tags: identification, weeds

I am trying to figure out what type of weed this is. I was thinking horseweed but the more I look at it the less I think so. This is a picture of young plants.

It is growing in New Hampshire in an area close to seasonal wetlands (muddy during spring but otherwise dry).

[image: id this week]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Flat Topped White Aster, *Doellingeria umbellata*](http://www.ct-botanical-society.org/galleries/doellingeriaumbe.html). They are native in your area.

See some comparison pics:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Are the flowers in that second picture small and white and held in flat-ish clusters on plants 2-5 feet tall?  If so, it *might* be [Ageratina adenophora](https://www.google.com/search?channel=np&q=Ageratina%20adenophora&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&tbm=isch&ei=n5GtU76gFZLooASyn4HoCQ).  The leaves are a bit narrow for this plant, but the up close pictures are of young plants and they may be in a bit shadier habitat than Ageratina prefers, which would probably affect the leaf shape somewhat, but the veining is very similar.  Have a look at the pictures linked and see if any of them look like what you've seen.  It is a fairly common invasive weed in some places, and prefers moist soils in the woods or near a stream.

Comment: Low light levels will tend to stimulate a wider, not a more narrow, leaf shape. Not really sure if this is it, but thanks for the effort.

Comment: I have added pictures of the plants now that they have grown up in hopes this might shed some light. I've seen several plants that have flowers that look nearly identical to these but all of them have different looking leaves.

Comment: It looks like dog fennel (Anthemis cotula or Chamaemelum) but the leaves are wrong on those